# Implementing an AddAtIndex method in a LinkedList

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, implementation

currently, I am working on implementing an AddAtIndex method and for the most part it seems to be working fine. However, my method is not passing my JUnit test and I can't seem to understand why. Thus, I have chosen to show the code I have done thus far:

```
**
     * Add an element to the list at the specified index
     * @param The index where the element should be added
     * @param element The element to add
     */
    public void add(int index, E element ) //Method should be O(1) time.
    {
        // TODO: Implement this method
        if (index < 0) { 
            System.out.println("Can't add an element at a negative index.");
        }
        int i = 0;
        LLNode<E> currentNode = head.next;
        while ( i < size ) {
            if ( i == index ) {
                LLNode<E> newNode = new LLNode<E>(element);
                LLNode<E> tempNode = new LLNode<E>(currentNode.data);

                currentNode.next = tempNode;
                currentNode.data = newNode.data;

                newNode.prev = currentNode.prev;
                newNode.next = tempNode;
                tempNode.prev = newNode;
                size++;
            }
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
            i++;
        }

    }
```

My thought process behind the code is that the method creates a new Node, then it replaces the data at the specified index of the linked list. However, the data at the node it is replacing is stored in a temporary node which is incremented in position to the next node after the new node. I am about 80% confident in my implementation though the code looks a bit sloppy. I have created a driver to demonstrate the implementation. The drivers code is as follows:

```
public class LinkedListDriver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        MyLinkedList<String> nameList = new MyLinkedList<String>();
        nameList.add("Hamadi");
        nameList.add("Ballo");
        nameList.add(1, "Salisu");
        nameList.add(2, "Galo");
        System.out.println(nameList.toString());
        System.out.println(nameList.size());
        nameList.set(2, "Abdullahi");
        System.out.println(nameList.toString());
        nameList.remove(1);
        System.out.println(nameList.toString());
        MyLinkedList<Integer> list1 = new MyLinkedList<Integer>();
        list1.add(65);
        list1.add(21);
        list1.add(42);
        System.out.println(list1.toString());
        list1.remove(0);
        System.out.println(list1.toString());
    }

}
```

The Output from the driver is as follows:

```
List: Hamadi, Salisu, Galo, Ballo, 
4
Replacing Galo with Abdullahi
List: Hamadi, Salisu, Abdullahi, Ballo, 
Removing Salisu from the list
List: Hamadi, Abdullahi, Ballo, 
List: 65, 21, 42, 
Removing 65 from the list
List: 21, 42,
```

The unit test fails however with the following error:

It fails at the AssertEquals method:

```
shortList.add(2, "E");
        shortList.add(3, "F");
        **assertEquals("AddAtIndex: at position 2 ", "E", shortList.get(2)); //fails here**
        assertEquals("AddAtIndex: at position 3 ", "F", shortList.get(3));
        assertEquals("AddAtIndex: List size is ", 6, shortList.size());
```

I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. I have this literally completely figured out, though I know that there is something a bit off about my AddAtindex method. Thanks!

Comment: use a debugger and see how the pointers are moving

Comment: From the initial output, I'd say the add method mostly works. I'm not sure what you're get method is doing to return you a bad value, though

Comment: You should also learn about `for`-loops: `for (int i = 0; i < size; i++ )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need that `tempNode`. Just create the `newNode` and insert it properly between `currentNode` and its previous node.

You should also consider the possibility of adding an element at the beginning (no previous) or end (no next) of the list.

Comment: There is an element at the beginning, it's an empty sentinel node known as head. I should have been more specific, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used head and tail as sentinel nodes. Created a new node to be added in the list.

```
public boolean add(E element) {
        // create new element
        LLNode<E> variable = new LLNode(element);
        variable.next = null;
        variable.prev = null;

        // if element is null, throw exception
        if (element == null) {
            // return false;
            throw new NullPointerException("Element is null");
        } else {
            // get the value stored in tail.prev in variable temp. 
            variable.prev = tail.prev;
            variable.next = tail;
            // now modify the tail node prev and new node next
            tail.prev = variable;

            // get prev node next link changed
            variable.prev.next = variable;

            // update size
            if (head.next.next != tail) {
                size++;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```